# inlineformset_factory widget aka field style

Tags: django, forms

I can't get widgets to work when they are used in conjunction with `inlineformset_factory`

```
class TravelsRelationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TravelsRelationsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_start'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datetimepicker'

    class Meta:
        model = TravelsRelations
        exclude = ('user',)

TravelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Travels, TravelsRelations, exclude=('user',))
```

I've tried width widget defined under `Meta` but it doesn't work either... I've searched over the net and neither solution worked... I just want to apply style to the input field.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out...

The solution is to add `form=MyChildModelForm` to the inlineformset_factory...

```
inlineformset_factory(Parent, Child, form=MyChildModelForm)
```

And the you define the widget under `Meta` of the `MyChildModelForm` as you usually would...